Is server based cpu mining worth it?
Can we get an updated version of this question. I believe the answers will be factually different because bitcoin was at a 1000 usd per coin and it is basically x 100 that now.
I have come into posession of a nice little server for very little money. It has an Intel Xeon cpu, 4 cores, and 32 gigs of RAM.
I want to buy a windows server 2016 liscense for. Install awesome miner on it and mine some bitcoin on it. It costs 0.20 usd per kw of power where I live
Now I don't expect to get rich of this. To be frank I would consider 10 usd a day a massive succsses. My livelyhood is in no way dependant on this. All I really would want is for this to produce some fun money.
Is this estimate achievable with this hardware?

The answers to this question (linked from the one you linked) are still correct. You can use a bitcoin mining profitability calculator such as this one (select SHA256 and your CPU) or review calculations in answers to this question

I’m afraid that CPU and GPU mining have been unprofitable for over a decade. While the exchange rate has gone up since then, the hashrate has gone even more.
